# An external frame of zeroes

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wrote this code. For some reason I get the new matrix, but the last value of the original matrix seems to be missing...

```
    public static char[][] Frame_of_zeros(char[][]a)//builds an external frame of zeroes
{

    char[][]c3=new char[a.length+1][a[0].length+1];
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<c3.length;i++)//left column is composed of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }
    for(int j=0,i=0;j<c3[0].length;j++)//upper row of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }
    for(int i=c3.length-1,j=0;j<c3[0].length;j++)//most lower row composed of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }
    for(int i=0,j=c3[0].length-1;i<c3.length;i++)//right column is composed of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }

    for(int i=1,k=0;i<c3.length-1&&k<a.length;i++,k++)//i for the modified and k is the original
    {
        for(int j=1,l=0;j<c3[0].length&&l<a[0].length-1;j++,l++)//j for the modified and l is the original
        {
            c3[i][j]=a[k][l];
        }
    }
    return c3;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to explain, in clear detail, what you _expect_ to happen and what _actually_ happens.  I.e. show a concrete example.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external frame means that you have to add two rows/columns each (left and right/ upper and lower), so you need to increase the size of your new matrix by an additional row and column.
The loops for setting the frame to 0 were fine.
At the last inner loop you set the reduced size of the initial matrix as condition instead of the new one as in the outer loop.

```
public static char[][] Frame_of_zeros(char[][]a)//builds an external frame of zeroes
{
    char[][]c3=new char[a.length+2][a[0].length+2];
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<c3.length;i++)//left column is composed of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }
    for(int j=0,i=0;j<c3[0].length;j++)//upper row of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }
    for(int i=c3.length-1,j=0;j<c3[0].length;j++)//most lower row composed of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }
    for(int i=0,j=c3[0].length-1;i<c3.length;i++)//right column is composed of zeroes
    {
        c3[i][j]='0';
    }

    for(int i=1,k=0;i<c3.length-1 && k<a.length;i++,k++)//i for the modified and k is the original
    {
        for(int j=1,l=0;j<c3[0].length-1 && l<a[0].length;j++,l++)//j for the modified and l is the original
        {
            c3[i][j]=a[k][l];
        }
    }
    return c3;
}
```